# От какого прилагательного образована сравнительная степень "слаще"?

Tags: словообразование

Если от "сладкий", то нет ли других примеров чередования д/щ?

Comment: Галина, прочитайте [здесь](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.35)

Comment: Спасибо, Сержик! Я оттудова и пришла - сама отвечала на Большом Вопросе об употреблении сласти - сладости... А как в комментах делаются шрифтовые выделения и гиперссылки?

Comment: Галина, шрифтовые выделения жирным выделяют тремя звездочками с двух сторон, а курсивом двумя звездочками с двух сторон. Гиперссылки делают так: в круглые скобки помещаете саму ссылку, а перед ней в квадратных скобках помещаете текст.

Comment: То есть всё... страшно сказать... С КЛАВИАТУРЫ?! Вульгарным набором символов?! ПАСИБКИ!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно таких же примеров не видно (cамое близкое: *хлёсткий - хлеще*, *гладкий - глаже*). Поэтому не исключено, что образование сравнительной формы случилось не через само прилагательное (как напр. в случае пары хороший - лучше). По ряду источников, "**пуще**" образовано от "**пусть**" (фонетически это выглядит правдоподобно), что наводит на мысль, не было ли "слаще" образовано от существительного "сласть" (во времена, когда расчленители речи на части и классификаторы этих частей не были столь влиятельны, как ныне):

Сладкий (обладающий вкусовым свойством всех сластей) -> имеющий больше сласти -> сла(**с**/т/**ч**)е -> сла**щ**е

Comment: Спасибо, Саша! Подробности - в ссылке Сержа.